# SQL Script File is failing but not showing an error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have ran this Script File on Oracle Application Express and it does not create my tables and does not state that I have errors. If you can't help that is okay, but I have been at this for hours and cannot figure out why it is not working

Here is my Script File:

```
CREATE TABLE GUEST_T
(GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
GUEST_NAME VARCHAR(25),
GUEST_ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT GUEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (GUEST_ID));

CREATE TABLE COMPANY_T
(GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
GUEST_NAME VARCHAR(25),
COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR(25),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
NO_OF_GUESTS INT,
CONSTRAINT COMPANY_PK PRIMARY KEY (GUEST_ID),
CONSTRAINT COMPANY_FK FOREIGN KEY (GUEST_ID) REFERENCES GUEST_T(GUEST_ID));

CREATE TABLE ACCOMMODATION_T
(ACCOMMODATION_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
ACCOMMODATION_TYPE VARCHAR(25),
PRICE DECIMAL (6,2),
CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACCOMMODATION_ID));

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_T
(EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(25),
HOURS_WORKED INT,
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID));

CREATE TABLE RECEPTIONIST_T
(EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(25),
HOURS_WORKED INT,
HOURLY_WAGE DECIMAL (4,2),
CONSTRAINT RECEPTIONIST_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID));

CREATE TABLE MANAGER_T
(EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(25),
HOURS_WORKED INT,
SALARY DECIMAL (10,2)
CONSTRAINT MANAGER_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID));

CREATE TABLE ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_T
(ACCOMMODATION_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
TIME REQUESTED NUMBER,
DATE_OF_USE DATE DEFAULTSYSDATE,
CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACCOMMODATION_ID, GUEST_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID),
CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ACCOMMODATION_ID) REFERENCES ACCOMMODATION_T(ACCOMMODATION_ID),
CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (GUEST_ID) REFERENCES GUEST_T(GUEST_ID),
CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID));

CREATE TABLE ROOM_T
(ROOM_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
FLOOR_NO NUMBER,
ROOM_PRICE DECIMAL (8,2),
ROOM_STATUS VARCHAR(20) CHECK (ROOM_STATUS IN (‘Vacant’, ‘Occupied’)),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_NO),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_FK FOREIGN KEY (FLOOR_NO) REFERENCES FLOOR_T(FLOOR_NO));

CREATE TABLE DOUBLE_ROOM_T
(ROOM_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
ROOM_PRICE DECIMAL (8,2),
ROOM_STATUS VARCHAR(20) CHECK (ROOM_STATUS IN (‘Vacant’, ‘Occupied’)),
ADJOINED VARCHAR(5) CHECK (ADJOINED IN (‘Yes’, ’No’)),
CONSTRAINT DOUBLE_ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_NO),
CONSTRAINT DOUBLE_ROOM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ROOM_NO) REFERENCES ROOM_T (ROOM_NO),
CONSTRAINT DOUBLE_ROOM_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (FLOOR_NO) REFERENCES FLOOR_T (FLOOR_NO));

CREATE TABLE RESERVATION_T
(ROOM_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
CHECK_IN_DATE DATE DEFAULTSYSDATE,
CHECK_OUT_DATE DATE DEFAULTSYSDATE,
NO_OF_ROOMS INT,
CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_NO, GUEST_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID),
CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ROOM_NO) REFERENCES ROOM_T(ROOM_NO),
CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (GUEST_ID) REFERENCES GUEST_T(GUEST_ID),
CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID));

CREATE TABLE FLOOR_T
(FLOOR_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
NO_OF_ROOMS INT,
CONSTRAINT FLOOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (FLOOR_NO));

CREATE TABLE FACILITY_T
(FACILITY_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
FACILITY_NAME VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT FACILITY_PK PRIMARY KEY (FACILITY_ID));
```

I have run this Script File on Oracle Application Express and it does not create my tables and does not state that I have errors. If you can't help that is okay, but I have been at this for hours and cannot figure out why it is not working.

Comment: you have some errorrs see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e88f9e29c42f3e87178f9f96c8cf5b80

Comment: RUN one create table at a time. Refresh your test sever to see if specific table is created or not (and I hope it is test server and not prod).

Answer (score 1):

There are *a lot* of issues in your script (and they do show up when the scripts runs). The most proeminent ones are:

- the same constraint name is used in several tables; a constraint name must be unique in a schema, you can prefix them with the table name to avoid clashes
- various typos : missing underscore, missing spaces, missing commas
- funky quotes `‘’` instead of regular quotes
- wrong table creation sequence: a parent table must be created before its dependant tables
- side note: you want to use `VARCHAR2`, that Oracle recommends to replace `VARCHAR`

Here is a new version of your script that works fine [in this DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=698cf2d5ea4209d5443b3aeb7a0609f8). All the changes are commented:

```
CREATE TABLE GUEST_T (
    GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    GUEST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    GUEST_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT GUEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (GUEST_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE COMPANY_T (
    GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    GUEST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
    NO_OF_GUESTS INT,
    CONSTRAINT COMPANY_PK PRIMARY KEY (GUEST_ID),
    CONSTRAINT COMPANY_FK FOREIGN KEY (GUEST_ID) REFERENCES GUEST_T(GUEST_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ACCOMMODATION_T (
    ACCOMMODATION_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ACCOMMODATION_TYPE VARCHAR2(25),
    PRICE DECIMAL (6,2),
    CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACCOMMODATION_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_T (
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    HOURS_WORKED INT,
    CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE RECEPTIONIST_T (
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    HOURS_WORKED INT,
    HOURLY_WAGE DECIMAL (4,2),
    CONSTRAINT RECEPTIONIST_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT RECEPTIONIST_T_EMPLOYEE_FK -- constraint name must be unique
        FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE MANAGER_T (
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    HOURS_WORKED INT,
    SALARY DECIMAL (10,2), -- missing comma here
    CONSTRAINT MANAGER_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT MANAGER_T_EMPLOYEE_FK -- constraint name must be unique
        FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_T (
    ACCOMMODATION_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    TIME_REQUESTED NUMBER,   -- missing underscore between TIME and REQUESTED
    DATE_OF_USE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, -- missing space between DEFAULT and SYSDATE
    CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACCOMMODATION_ID, GUEST_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ACCOMMODATION_ID) REFERENCES ACCOMMODATION_T(ACCOMMODATION_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (GUEST_ID) REFERENCES GUEST_T(GUEST_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ACCOMMODATION_REQUEST_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

-- must be created before the dependant tables (ROOM_T, DOUBLE_ROOM_T, ...)
CREATE TABLE FLOOR_T (
    FLOOR_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    NO_OF_ROOMS INT,
    CONSTRAINT FLOOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (FLOOR_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE ROOM_T (
    ROOM_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FLOOR_NO NUMBER,
    ROOM_PRICE DECIMAL (8,2),
    ROOM_STATUS VARCHAR2(20) CHECK (ROOM_STATUS IN ('Vacant', 'Occupied')), -- funky quotes ‘’
    CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ROOM_FK FOREIGN KEY (FLOOR_NO) REFERENCES FLOOR_T(FLOOR_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE DOUBLE_ROOM_T (
    ROOM_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ROOM_PRICE DECIMAL (8,2),
    ROOM_STATUS VARCHAR2(20) CHECK (ROOM_STATUS IN ('Vacant', 'Occupied')), -- funky quotes ‘’
    ADJOINED VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (ADJOINED IN ('Yes', 'No')),  -- funky quote ‘’
    CONSTRAINT DOUBLE_ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_NO),
    CONSTRAINT DOUBLE_ROOM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ROOM_NO) REFERENCES ROOM_T (ROOM_NO)
    -- CONSTRAINT DOUBLE_ROOM_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (FLOOR_NO) REFERENCES FLOOR_T (FLOOR_NO) -- there is no such column
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVATION_T (
    ROOM_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    GUEST_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CHECK_IN_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,  -- missing space between DEFAULT and SYSDATE
    CHECK_OUT_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, -- missing space between DEFAULT and SYSDATE
    NO_OF_ROOMS INT,
    CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_NO, GUEST_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ROOM_NO) REFERENCES ROOM_T(ROOM_NO),
    CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (GUEST_ID) REFERENCES GUEST_T(GUEST_ID),
    CONSTRAINT RESERVATION_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FACILITY_T (
    FACILITY_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FACILITY_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    CONSTRAINT FACILITY_PK PRIMARY KEY (FACILITY_ID)
);
```